# Look-back pwd until expression found on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Possible folder layouts:

```
path/to/a/project1/FOO-****/some/where/inside
path/to/another/project2/FOO-****/some/where/else/inside
```

I am looking for single line bash command that can drop me into a location `FOO-****` which can be in any form, `FOO-source`, `FOO-system-test` or `FOO-unit-test` or any similarly named folder, while my pwd could be anywhere inside that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this, searching backwards for a FOO* directory :

```
while [[ $PWD != / ]]; do [[ `basename "$PWD"` != "FOO"* ]] && cd .. || break ; done
```

Comment: It will change the working directory to `/` if there is no match.

Comment: @Dzienny Yes indeed, however to me this solution is more than enough bearing in mind the unclear requirements of the OP